# Conversion of non-linear equation to linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to convert non-linear equation with four variables into linear equation using basic algebraic techniques? If not, what are the techniques in algebra or calculus which can be use to linearized a non-linear equation? Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Usually non-linear equations remain that way, except in some very specific (almost trivial) cases. Linearizing an equation just comes down to ignoring part of it, which changes the solution.

Comment: @Lukas Rollier. It means that not all non-linear equation can be converted into linear equation?

Comment: Well, yes, by ignoring higher order terms, but very often this is of no use

Comment: @Lukas Rollier. I can just ignore the higher order terms to linearize a non-linear equation?

Comment: When you assume them to be small, yes. This is for example what happens when we say $\ln(1+x) \sim x$ for $x$ small. In general, ignoring higher order terms doesn't really get you much useful information though

Comment: @Lukas Rollier. I see. Thank You for the information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103029/discussion-between-hydr0gen-and-lukas-rollier).